# Exercism Python Bob

Tags: python

I'm learning Python through Exercism.IO, I'm currently on the `Bob` problem where the object of the problem is as follows:

> Bob is a lackadaisical teenager. In conversation, his responses are very limited.
>   Bob answers 'Sure.' if you ask him a question.
>   He answers 'Whoa, chill out!' if you yell at him.
>   He says 'Fine. Be that way!' if you address him without actually saying
>   anything.
>   He answers 'Whatever.' to anything else.

So far I've passed a few tests and I'm stuck at a point where it's suppose to return `whatever` but all the characters are integers, so of course it's not working.

Here's where I'm failing:

```
def test_only_numbers(self):
    self.assertEqual(
        'Whatever.', bob.hey('1, 2, 3')
    )
```

All the characters are integers and my test to see if they're yelling looks like this:

```
def is_yelling(self):
    return self.sentence == self.sentence.upper()
```

Obviously the characters are the same when upper or lower case because they're numbers so the program thinks they're yelling. My question is how can I refactor this program to make it so that when the assertion is all numbers, it won't count it as yelling?

```
def hey(what):
    sentence = SentenceThinker(what)
    if sentence.is_silence():
        return "Fine. Be that way!"
    elif sentence.is_yelling():
        return "Whoa, chill out!"
    elif sentence.is_question():
        return "Sure."
    else:
        return "Whatever."


class SentenceThinker(object):

    def __init__(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence

    def is_yelling(self):
        return self.sentence == self.sentence.upper()

    def is_question(self):
        return self.sentence.endswith("?")

    def is_silence(self):
        return not self.sentence
```

Comment: Have you tried checking for the input type before doing your tests? `if not any(c.isdigit() for c in self.sentence): # Has no digits, proceed` or something like that.

Comment: Or just compare the lower version to the original for equality

Comment: consider [`string.isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)

Comment: @Hamms: Pedantic point: You mean `str.isupper` (and your link is correct). There is a `string` module, so saying `string.isupper` gives the wrong impression. Otherwise, you're correct, and should probably make that an answer (it's better than what's been posted since it solves the exact problem: Determining that a string contains at least one cased character, and all cased characters are uppercase).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I do indeed! Thank you

Comment: Man you Python guys are awesome. Thanks for all the input everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider using the built-in String method [`str.isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)

Comment: That worked, I still failed one assertion, but this helped a lot thank you. I know how to fix the last fail anyways